# Does phantomjs regularly clear its cache automatically?

Tags: phantomjs, browser-cache

I need to change the default time of automatic cache clear for Phantomjs if there is such a feature. Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should be the feature that you are looking for:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10357

```
page.clearMemoryCache()
```

Answer (score 7):

Each PhantomJS process has its own in-memory cache, so there is no need to clear it between script executions. You can let PhantomJS save the cache in disk, so that it persists accross executions. See the [`--disk-cache` option](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html).

There is no way to clear the cache *during* a script execution.

`localStorage` on the other hand is persisted every time and you cannot turn it off. So you may need to add the following snippet before exiting PhantomJS.

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    localStorage.clear();
});
```