# How to clean cache and cookies in Selenium using PhantomJS in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

I am using Selenium with the PhantomJS Webdriver on Python 2.7 and I don't see any references in the documentation about cleaning the cache. Is there a way to clean the cache and cookies? I have seen functions in PhantomJS that can do it, but how to use them in Selenium ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does phantomjs regularly clear its cache automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875584/does-phantomjs-regularly-clear-its-cache-automatically)

Comment: @franklin, there is nothing about selenium in that answer. As I said, I am writing a program in Python 2.7 and use Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: It depends on ***how*** you're using the webdriver. If a webdriver is being launched between tests, it doesn't matter, because the relaunch will automatically clear PhantomJS's cache. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @franklin, I am trying to test a pop-up windows, generated by js. It shows available train tickets. The problem is, that sometimes my tests does not return the right number of tickets. I counted by myself and compared it to the test results. I thought, it might be because of cache and cookies.

Comment: We need to see source code. We need to see ***how*** you're launching these webdriver requests. See my comment above. If your driver is being reset between queries the cache should be automatically cleared.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
driver.get("about:blank")
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.execute_script('localStorage.clear();')
```

I put the driver.get("about:blank") in there just in case the current site has changed the Javascript environment in unexpected ways.

You could also just destroy the driver and create a new one, but that might be slightly less efficient (you'd have to measure it on your setup to know for sure).

Comment: destroy the driver and create a new one is work for me, thanks