# PhantomJS HTTP request cache (or something else?)

Tags: phantomjs

I wrote a small Bash script which runs a few PhantomJS tasks.

For example:

```
./node_modules/.bin/phantomjs "phantomjs/snapshot.js" "$url" >file.html
```

As you see, I use the logged info from PhantomJS to write it to a file.

I ran the command on a URL with JavaScript errors. For some unknown reason each time I now run that command with the same URL I still get the errors... Although everything's fine if I do the same with a different Linux user. Also, if I use a different URL, everything is also fine (but I need to use the one which throws errors).

Is there a way PhantomJS uses cached response? I tried to add clearCookies() and clearMemoryCache() methods before opening the page, also tried to add random parameter on each call, but nothing helped...

PhantomJS is the latest version.

Comment: localStorage is the only thing that is persistent between runs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does phantomjs regularly clear its cache automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875584/does-phantomjs-regularly-clear-its-cache-automatically)

Comment: Thanks, you actually helped. I found out that PhantomJS stores localStorage inside /home/USER/.local/share/data/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS, so removing from there helped.

Comment: There is no button to confirm duplicate. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the broken call made an entry to localStorage, which then was causing all other errors. Apparently PhantomJS keeps the localStorage on a file, so removing appropriate entry from `/home/USER/.local/share/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS` cleared the localStorage and the problem is gone now.